# tkinter: how to get Spinbox to reveal whether up or down button has been pushed

Tags: tkinter

In Tcl, you can use a simple percent substitution, `%d`, in a spinbox command to tell whether the up or down button has been pushed, like this:

```
spinbox .datespin -width 9 -command {
    set way %d
    datespin $way %W
}
```

I'm still trying to see how to get the same thing to happen with a Spinbox in tkinter, which doesn't seem to like the `%d` substitution (it gives me syntax errors). The tkinter documentation I've looked at so far hasn't helped. Can somebody tell me how to get a Spinbox to reveal whether the up or down button has been pushed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saw this question as I was researching something else. Even though this is an old question, I thought I might as well answer it in case you haven't found an answer elsewhere.

You'll have to use the universal widget "register" method (i.e., you can call this method on any widget) to wrap your Python function into a Tcl wrapper in order to use the percent substitutions. (As a side, you have to do the same thing in order to get a validatecommand working in an Entry widget.)

In order to send the percent substitution to your callback, specify a tuple instead of just the callable, with your substitutions as elements in the tuple (see example below).

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def up_or_down(direction):
    print(direction)

tcl_up_or_down = root.register(up_or_down)

spinbox = tk.Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=10, command=(tcl_up_or_down, '%d'))
spinbox.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!